# Passing a record from a list, to a combo box, then parsing part of it to return a value to a method

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

There's three elements here.

1. A list of Trip Expenses with a bunch of methods
2. A windows form (tripChoose is a combo box and listExpenses is a list box)
3. The object itself (Trip Expense)

I want to pass only e.Trip to the "ToFind" method. Instead, the entire string is passed. I need to parse out only e.Trip somehow. Any ideas? I still want both the amount and trip to display in the combo box but I need only e.Trip to pass to the method. See below:

In the form, I have this

```
private void LoadExpenseListSums()
{
    expenseTotalSelect.Items.Clear();
    var dateSorted =
        from e in roster
        group e by e.Trip into tripGroup
        select new { Trip = tripGroup.Key, SumAmount = tripGroup.Sum(e => e.Amount) };
    foreach (var e in dateSorted)
        tripChoose.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} | ${1}", e.Trip, e.SumAmount));
}

private void tripChoose_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listExpenses.Items.Clear();
    tripTextBox.Clear();
    descriptionTextBox.Clear();
    amountTextBox.Clear();
    paymentMethodTextBox.Clear();
    noteTextBox.Clear();
    IEnumerable<TripExpense> selectedExpenses = roster.ToFind((string)tripChoose.SelectedItem);
    foreach (TripExpense item in selectedExpenses)
        listExpenses.Items.Add(item);            
}
```

LoaExpenseListSums happens when the form is loaded, I want e.Trip to be the only part in `roster.ToFind((string)tripChoose.SelectedItem);` to be passed to this method

```
        public IEnumerable<TripExpense> ToFind(string trip)
    {
        return this.Where(e => e.Trip == trip);
    }
```

It works fine if LoadExpenseListSums is rewritten as such:

```
        private void LoadExpenseListSums()
        {
            expenseTotalSelect.Items.Clear();
            var dateSorted =
                from e in roster
                group e by e.Trip into tripGroup
select new { Trip = tripGroup.Key };
            foreach (var e in dateSorted)
                tripChoose.Items.Add(e.Trip);
        }
```

Comment: I am lost, do you have a question somewhere ? Can't you split based on `|` and get the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I woul like to take little different approach to do it.

declare a temporary class.

```
 public class tempTrip
  {
       public string Trip;
       public string dispText { get; set;} 
  }
```

Now change LoadExpenseListSums() function

```
 private void LoadExpenseListSums() 
 {     expenseTotalSelect.Items.Clear();     
        var dateSorted =         
                     from e in roster        
                     group e by e.Trip into tripGroup         
                      select new  tempTrip 
                       { Trip = tripGroup.Key, dispText = string.Format("{0} | ${1}",  tripGroup.Key, tripGroup.Sum(e => e.Amount)).Tostring() };     

          tripChoose.DisplayMember =  "dispText";
          tripChoose.DataSource = dateSorted.ToList<tempTrip>();       
}
```

Now in tripChoose_SelectedIndexChanged , you can write

```
 IEnumerable<TripExpense> selectedExpenses = roster.ToFind(((tempTrip)tripChoose.SelectedItem).Trip); 
 // this will give you Trip from the selected item.
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting this displayed in my trip choose pull-down list: Payroll.ExpenseRecorderForm+tempTrip

I just need to get that formatted string to display

Comment: make dispText in class a property. It will work. see the changed code.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're doing this:

```
foreach (var e in dateSorted) 
    tripChoose.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} | ${1}", e.Trip, e.SumAmount));
```

And then, you want to accomplish this:

```
roster.ToFind((string)tripChoose.SelectedItem);
```

But, when you accomplish the ToFind thing, you wanto that it takes only the e.Trip, not e.SumAmount.

Now, supposing that what I've wrote is the thing that you're asking for, you can do simple things...

First, make shure that the `string.Format("{0} | ${1}", e.Trip, e.SumAmount)` is written as you have it on here. Then you can delete the unwanted part of `tripChoose.SelectedItem` based on the | character of formatting. As an idea, you can use a for like this:

```
string myItem = (string)tripChoose.SelectedItem;
int removingIndex;
for (int i = 0; i < myItem.Length; i++)
{
    if (myItem[i] == '|')
    {
        removingIndex = i;
        i = myItem.Length;
    }
}
myItem.Remove(removingIndex);
```

Is it the best way...? No, but it's the basic idea.

Now, you can use `roster.ToFind` with the `myItem` string that has only the e.Trip part.

Hope it helps